# Why did Robot begin to risk himself?

Tags: invincible

In the streaming series adaptation of *Invincible*, Robot initially fights with a series of drones, which has the advantage of keeping his actual body safe from the fighting—so safe that apparently nothing had ever threatened it.

However, after creating a body modeled on Rex with Robot's personality and memories, this new version of Robot chooses to abandon the previous strategy and go into battle by using one of these drones as a sort of suit of armor—in spite of the fact that this exposes him to considerably more existential danger than his previous strategy, still limits him to the combat power of the drone, and by his own admission, affects his combat skills, since he is now afraid for his safety.

Why did Robot abandon his previous strategy of remote-controlled drones and start risking his own body?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this has been answered in the show. In the comics, the initial reason is the range of his transmitter. Specifically, Rudy can't operate the robots from Earth while they're in space

It's not clear afterwards why he continues to do so. The most likely reason seems to be that he's attempting to strengthen his bond with Monster Girl (you'll remember that they've already been on one date, at this point in the show)